# How to generate a dynamic div with a button with PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi guys I want to generate this div `question` using a button but the thing is this div is dynamic. Here's my code. There's no javascript code for the button yet because I don't know how yet.

surveycontent.php

```
    <div id="question">

              </div> 

       <div class="col-md-2">
       <input type="submit" name="addsection" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Section" id="addsection" />

       </div>

    <script>

        function load_questions(){

            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php??main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


        }
</script>
```

ajax.php This is the code behind the div id in surveycontent.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("server","username","","password") or die ("Cannot connect to the database!");

$subcat=isset($_GET["subcategory"])?$_GET["subcategory"]:"";

if($subcat !="") {

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_subcat = $subcat ");
    echo "<select>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<option value='$row[question_id] selected'>" ; echo $row["questiontitle"]; echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

}



?>
```

My question is whats the code that will generate this div dynamically meaning the data inside it will have unique names.

Comment: Where you call the function `load_questions`?

Comment: can you please add code snippet..